# Form not writing to database

Tags: php, html, sql

So Im kind of new to php and I have this form in reg.php file

```
<form method="post" action="scripts/signup.php" class="ui form"">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>UserName</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Choose a unique UserName">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>E-mail</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-Mail" required>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                </div>


                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="ui  big inverted red button" value="submit">Register</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </form>
```

and i have signup.php which contains the registration code

```
    <?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $username = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $name = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $address = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
    $email = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);



        // cccheck if username is already in db
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $rescheck = mysqli_num_rows($res);

        //if the query returns a row or multiple
        if ($rescheck > 0) {
            header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=usernamesame");
            exit();

        } else {

            //password hashing
            $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


            //write user too db
            $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users(username, name1, address, email, pass)VALUES ('$username','$name','$address','$email','$hashed_password');";

            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insert);

            echo $results;
            header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=succcess");
            exit();

        }




} else {
    header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=Error");
    exit();
}
```

The dbh.php contains nothing but variables and set up for the db, the main line is

```
$conn =  mysqli_connect($server_name, $username,$password,$db_Name);
```

The issue is when i submit the form i get the success message but on further inspection the user is not added to the db.

any help is appreciated greatly

Sorry peeps it was all my fault i didn't have the pass set to receive such a large string. Thanks all for trying to help.

@LahiruTM was the most helpful answer, Its always the smallest thing

Comment: Did you have an sql error ?

Comment: Check for an error: mysqli_error($con)

Comment: Your code will redirect to the success page regardless of the result of the query.

Comment: add a space beetween users and ( in your request : **INSERT INTO users (username** and an other here **pass) VALUES**

Comment: Also you may check `echo $sql_insert; die();` to see how your query is looking there is lots that can be wrong there, missing variable that insert is expecting database column different name or different format.. and so on..

Comment: Change the `mysqli_query` to this one so that you can get the error if there is any happening during the query `$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insert) or die(mysqli_error());`. Also removed the `;` which is before the last double quotes in your `$sql_insert` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the bottom of your signup.php file comment below two lines which is echo the result and header redirection. Then echo $sql_insert to see executed sql query. Once you submit the form, get that query and run it in phpmyadmin sql query section. If anything wrong in the query, you will easily find it. Likewise use small trics to troubleshoot your problems.

```
        //write user too db
        $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users(username, name1, address, email, pass)VALUES ('$username','$name','$address','$email','$hashed_password');";

        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insert);
        echo $sql_insert;
        //echo $results;
        //header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=succcess");
        exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can modify your script php like this :

```
 <?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $username = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $name = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $address = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
    $email = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);



        // cccheck if username is already in db
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $rescheck = mysqli_num_rows($res);

        //if the query returns a row or multiple
        if ($rescheck > 0) {
            header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=usernamesame");
            exit();

        } else {

            //password hashing
            $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


            //write user too db
            $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users (username, name1, address, email, pass) VALUES ('$username','$name','$address','$email','$hashed_password');";

            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insert);

            echo $results;
            header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=succcess");
            exit();
        }

} else {
    header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=Error");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL insert stmt, you are closing the VALUES with a semicolon.

Change your statement to this:

```
 $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users(username, name1, address, email, pass)VALUES ('$username','$name','$address','$email','$hashed_password') ";
```

For further notice, please use PDO for security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code this way. If there is any error, it will be displayed on your screen.
And you don't need to echo the result as your are redirecting to another page.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $username = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $name = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $address = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
    $email = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);



        // cccheck if username is already in db
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $rescheck = mysqli_num_rows($res);

        //if the query returns a row or multiple
        if ($rescheck > 0) {
            header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=usernamesame");
            exit();

        } else {

            //password hashing
            $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


            //write user too db
            $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users(username, name1, address, email, pass)VALUES ('$username','$name','$address','$email','$hashed_password')";

            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insert) or die(mysqli_error());

            echo $results;
            header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=succcess");
            exit();

        }




} else {
    header("Location: ../reg.php?reg=Error");
    exit();
}
```